# Можно ли добавить файл в репозиторий, не копируя его

Tags: git, github

На сайте **Github** можно перетащить файл, тогда он добавится в репозиторий. Но если использовать **git**, то придётся скопировать репозиторий на диск. **Вопрос**: можно ли загрузить файл (сделать коммит) на гитхаб, не клонируя все коммиты к себе на компьютер, используя `git`.

Comment: Теоретически можно. Но возможно достаточно просто ограничиться одним последним коммитом и не нужно будет скачивать всё

Comment: @AlexeyTen, нужно делать git pull, а эта команда копирует содержимое.

Comment: https://github.blog/2020-12-21-get-up-to-speed-with-partial-clone-and-shallow-clone/

Comment: @AlexeyTen, спасибо. Параметр depth делает то, что я хотел.